# While trying to run a query I get this "Error: Call to a member function query() on string" and can't seem to find a fix

Tags: php

Setting up a website and trying to get an image to display using values from a database.

Tried changing variables, and redoing the databse, not much has worked. Here is the different code used, starting with the problem area. the error says the issue is with 'line 5'. And secondly the database connection code.

```
<?php
    require "../includes/header.php";
    require "../includes/db_handler.php";
    $sql = "SELECT * from products WHERE featured = 1";
    $featured = $db->query($sql);
?>

------------------------------------------------------


<?php
    $server = "*******";
    $username = "*****";
    $password = ""; 
    $db = "******";

    $conn = mysqli_connect($server, $username, $password, $db);
```

Comment: The error is correct. Your `$db` is a string (see `$db = "******";` line). You need to use `$conn` instead: `$conn->query($sql);`

Comment: That fixed it yeah. Cheers for the assist. :)